# SQL Query not Returning Anyting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am executing a simple query on SSMS:

```
SELECT TOP (10) * 
FROM pitch_aggregate 
WHERE BAT_NAME_FULL = 'A.J. Burnett';
```

that is returning nothing when I manually type in A.J. Burnett.  However, when I copy the output from the screenshot below (right-click, copy, paste) into the above query, it returns rows as expected.  Visually, there is no difference between what I typed in manually and copied/pasted.

Please see the following screenshot:

[A.J. Burnett as in the data]

[image: 1]

This query:

```
SELECT BAT_NAME_FULL
FROM pitch_aggregate
WHERE BAT_NAME_FULL LIKE '%Burnett%'
    AND BAT_NAME_FULL LIKE '%'+CHAR(9)+'%' 
    OR BAT_NAME_FULL LIKE '%'+CHAR(10)+'%' 
    OR BAT_NAME_FULL LIKE '%'+CHAR(11)+'%';
```

returns nothing.

This query:

```
SELECT TOP (1) CONVERT(varbinary(100),BAT_NAME_FULL)
FROM pitch_aggregate;
```

returns

0x412E4A2E204275726E657474

This query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pitch_aggregate 
WHERE BAT_NAME_FULL LIKE '%A.J.%'
ORDER BY BAT_NAME_FULL
;
```

returns multiple rows, including those with A.J. Burnett.

Building on the previous query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pitch_aggregate 
WHERE BAT_NAME_FULL LIKE '%A.J. B%'
ORDER BY BAT_NAME_FULL;
```

returns multiple rows, including those with A.J. Burnett.

Mystery solved!  The correct space character should have an ASCII code of 32, but it was encoded as 160 in the table.

Comment: show us sample data

Comment: Can you share some sample data that you’re querying against?

Comment: White space type or case sensitive encoding used in schema or possibly you are not looking at the same data as what you are querying against. Hard to say if you do not include the *actual* values in that specific tables and create some type of [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, all.  Please see the screenshot I just uploaded to the original question.

Comment: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2805b0be8e318891bc69aac61e05305d)*

Comment: Thanks, just copied the output directly from SSMS to the db<>fiddle code and of course, it looks as expected, ie, didn't change anything after executing.

Comment: What is the value you get, if you change `BAT_NAME_FULL` to `CONVERT(varbinary(100),BAT_NAME_FULL)` in the `SELECT` in your image?

Comment: Here is the output:      0x412E4A2E204275726E657474

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved! The correct space character should have an ASCII code of 32, but it was encoded as 160 in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to check if your field contains:
**Horizontal Tab(char(9)), New Line(char(10)) or Vertical Tab(char(11))**

```
SELECT BAT_NAME_FULL
FROM pitch_aggregate
WHERE BAT_NAME_FULL LIKE '%Burnett%'
AND (BAT_NAME_FULL LIKE '%'+CHAR(9)+'%' OR BAT_NAME_FULL LIKE '%'+CHAR(10)+'%'
OR BAT_NAME_FULL LIKE '%'+CHAR(11)+'%')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - nothing returned! 

Answer (score 0):

I would shrink your query string down to just '%A.J.%'.  This way, no issue of leading/trailing spaces, tabs, white-noise characters you cant see.  THEN see the actual content once it is returned

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - multiple rows returned, including for A.J. Burnett.